# How to update a field in access with data from another field with conditions?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in MS Access. I have a table "Jan 2021" with a field "1st Fill Sold" and I would like to update "1st Fill Sold" with the dates from the field "Fill Sold Date", which is located in the table "WAG Data" but only if the field "Fill Nbr" (also located in "WAG Data") is equal to 1. How would I go about writing the SQL code for this? So far I have only managed to be able to update "1st Fill Sold" with a constant rather than the varying dates from "Fill Sold Date". I have created a relationship between the Rx number fields (named "Rx #" and "Rx Nbr" respectively) from both tables, so that "1st Fill Sold" will be updated with the date from "Fill Sold Date" that corresponds to the matching Rx number.

For example I want to update the "1st Fill Sold" date for Rx # 312 in "Jan 2021" with the date from "Fill Sold Date" corresponding to Rx Nbr 312 and Fill Nbr 1, which would be located in the table "WAG Data".

EDIT: Adding example tables to make the question clearer

Table: Jan 2021

1. | Rx # | 1st Fill Sold |
2. | 312  | _____________ |
3. | 496  | _____________ |
4. | 811  | _____________ |

Table: WAG Data

1. | Rx Nbr | Fill Nbr | Fill Sold Date |
2. |  312   |    1     |   01/05/2021   |
3. |  312   |    2     |   02/07/2021   |
4. |  312   |    3     |   03/07/2021   |
5. |  496   |    2     |   01/27/2021   |
6. |  496   |    3     |   02/28/2021   |
7. |  811   |    1     |   01/15/2021   |
8. |  811   |    2     |   02/15/2021   |

**Desired Result:**
Table: Jan 2021

1. | Rx # | 1st Fill Sold |
2. | 312  |  01/05/2021  |
3. | 496  | ____________ |
4. | 811  |  01/15/2021  |

### So I want to fill in the missing dates in the field "1st Fill Sold" in the Jan 2021 table with those in the "Fill Sold Date" field in the WAG Data table, but only if the value in "Fill Nbr" in the WAG Data table is equal to 1. Thus, the second row of Jan 2021 table would have 312 under "Rx #" and 01/05/2021 under "1st Fill Sold" after the update and Rx #'s 496 and 811 having the correct corresponding dates for 1st Fill Sold as well.

---

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the question much, much clearer.

Comment: Alright I added example tables, let me know if this still doesn't cut it.

Comment: Determining "first" likely involves an aggregate query. An UPDATE action cannot involve an aggregate query. Would have to use domain aggregate function or VBA looping recordset. Saving calculated data, especially result of aggregation, is usually a bad idea. If it can be calculated for update, it can be calculated when needed. So, calculate this when needed, don't save. You have a table for each year/month? Also a bad idea.  What happened to Rx 496 fill 1?

Comment: The data I am given that our clinic generates is separated into Month/Year based on when the Rx was written (when the patient came in and had an appointment). The information sent to us by the pharmacies, such as Walgreens, that fill these Rx's is not and is formatted differently. Rx 496 fill #1 is left out because there will be times when there is no data from WAG because fill #1 was filled before the starting date of the data we receive from WAG and I wanted to show that, that is okay. So, is what you're saying that what I am looking for is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing everyone with your description of finding first entry when what you're really asking for is the Fill Nbr field to be 1

If you create your filter query (qListFirstData) as

```
SELECT [WAG Data].[RX Nbr], [WAG Data].[Fill Sold Date]
FROM [WAG Data]
WHERE [WAG Data].[Fill Nbr]=1;
```

And then use that query to create and run your update query as

```
UPDATE [Jan 2021] 
INNER JOIN qFindFirstData 
ON [Jan 2021].[RX#] = qFindFirstData.[RX Nbr] 
SET [Jan 2021].[First Fill Sold] = [Fill Sold Date]
WHERE [Jan 2021].[First Fill Sold] Is Null;
```